# Task continuous execution even after exception

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

The method **RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual** that is within the Task below is returning an exception already handled in the method itself, the problem is that the Task continues execution of the next line **var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);** which depends on the method **AbrirDataAtual()** to be executed, it also throws an exception. I have tried to treat within the method, put the task inside a Try / catch, but nothing works, there is always the exception in the method **ListaLinksDownlaod** and should not even get there.

How can I stop the execution of the task, such as when we send a CancellationToken, but this time, when an exception occurs.

```
private async Task<List<IWebElement>> Acessar(IWebDriver driver, string data, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

        RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

        RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data);

        var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

        MethodInvoker action = delegate { pgbStatus.Maximum = links.Count(); };
        pgbStatus.BeginInvoke(action);

        return links;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to tell for sure without seeing actual implementation of `AbrirDataAtual`, but it definitely looks like this method is handling exception that should not be handled there.

Generally, method should handle exception **only** if it can handle it *properly* (by *properly* I mean it can recover application to the state where program can safely continue, inform user about the error, etc.), otherwise it should not handle it at all and let the exception propagate to the caller(s) of the method.

Based on description of your problem, `AbrirDataAtual` doesn't (and can't) handle the exception *properly*, so you should not catch the exception there (or if excetion must be caught there, you should [re-throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception) it). All following methods (including `ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod`) will be skipped up to the point, where exception is handled. Problem solved!

The following example shows how to handle the exception directly in the task (after you remove exception handling in `AbrirDataAtual`). But it's likely that it's still not the best place for such exception handler, but again, finding such place would require complete source code so take it just as an example to clarify what I'm talking about:

```
private async Task<List<IWebElement>> Acessar(IWebDriver driver, string data, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

        RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

        try
        {
            RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data);

            var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

            MethodInvoker action = delegate { pgbStatus.Maximum = links.Count(); };
            pgbStatus.BeginInvoke(action);

            return links;
        }
        catch (Exception)//Use more specific exception type if possible
        {
            //Do all neccesary to properly handle the exception
        }
    });
}
```

If you still believe that `AbrirDataAtual` method is the right place to handle the exception, an alternative approach is to modify `AbrirDataAtual` to return boolean flag indicating success/failure of it's operation, e.g.:

```
bool AbrirDataAtual(IWebDriver driver, string data)
{
    try
    {
        //Do all the neccessary stuff
        ...

        //Indicate that AbrirDataAtual succeeded
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        //Handle exception properly
        ...

        //Indicate that AbrirDataAtual failed
        return false;
    }
}

private async Task<List<IWebElement>> Acessar(IWebDriver driver, string data, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        LoginNgin.Login(config.User, config.Password, driver);

        RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirRelatoriosEstaticos(driver);

        if (RelatoriosEstaticos.AbrirDataAtual(driver, data))
        {
            //Continue execution
            var links = ListArquivos.ListaLinksDownlaod(driver);

            MethodInvoker action = delegate { pgbStatus.Maximum = links.Count(); };
            pgbStatus.BeginInvoke(action);

            return links;
        }
        else
        {
            //AbrirDataAtual failed
            return null;
            //or throw exception if appropriate
            throw new Exception();
        }
    });
}
```